# Jersey client: How to add a list as query parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm creating a Jersey client for a GET service that has a List as query parameter. According to the [documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e247), it's possible to have a List as a query parameter (this information is also at [@QueryParam](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) javadoc), check it out:

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and java.util.UUID.fromString(String)); or
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
>
> Sometimes parameters may contain more than one value for the same name. If this is the case then types in 4) may be used to obtain all values.

However, I can't figure out how to add a List query parameter using Jersey client.

I understand alternative solutions are:

1. Use POST instead of GET;
2. Transform the List into a JSON string and pass it to the service.

The first one is not good, because the proper HTTP verb for the service is GET. It is a data retrieval operation.

The second will be my option if you can't help me out. :)

I'm also developing the service, so I may change it as needed.

Thanks!

**Update**

Client code (using json)

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client.resource(uri.toString());

SearchWrapper sw = new SearchWrapper(termo, pagina, ordenacao, hits, SEARCH_VIEW, navegadores);

MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
params.add("user", user.toUpperCase()); 
params.add("searchWrapperAsJSON", (new Gson()).toJson(sw));

ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource .path("/listar")
                                            .queryParams(params)
                                            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AuthenticationHelper.getBasicAuthHeader())
                                            .get(ClientResponse.class);

SearchResultWrapper busca = clientResponse.getEntity(new GenericType<SearchResultWrapper>() {});
```

Comment: can you give jersey client code here...

Comment: yogesh, I added the client code.

Comment: If i understand your problem statement, you can pass list of values as Query parameter by adding multiple values to same key.
If "searchWrapper" is the key and you want to pass multiple values to it:
build URL like this : //YourURL?searchWrapper=value1&searchWrapper=value2&searchWrapper=value3

may be you need to insert values multiple times to same key if your MultivaluedMap supports it.

Comment: Thanks, @ThammeGowda! I haven't tested it but it seems to do the trick as [MultivaluedMap javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) for add method states: _Add a value to the current list of values for the supplied key_.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`@GET` does support List of Strings

**Setup**: 
Java : 1.7 
Jersey version : 1.9

**Resource**

```
@Path("/v1/test")
```

**Subresource**:

```
// receive List of Strings
@GET
@Path("/receiveListOfStrings")
public Response receiveListOfStrings(@QueryParam("list") final List<String> list){
    log.info("receieved list of size="+list.size());
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

**Jersey testcase**

```
@Test
public void testReceiveListOfStrings() throws Exception {
    WebResource webResource = resource();
    ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource.path("/v1/test/receiveListOfStrings")
            .queryParam("list", "one")
            .queryParam("list", "two")
            .queryParam("list", "three")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(200, responseMsg.getStatus());
}
```

Comment: Just as a note for others, if you are writing the URL directly in a browser you must repeat the parameter name:

..?list=one&list=two&list=three

Comment: Is this truly a list / is order guaranteed to be respected? Given it seems like it's a multivalued map that Jersey returns as a list I wonder if there can be issues with order not being preserved

Comment: yeah. ?list=one&list=two&list=three is not that useful. as list=one,two,three - that's why I pares it manually from string to list.. `List<String> argList = List.of(argString.split("\\s*,\\s*"))`

Answer (score 31):

If you are sending anything other than simple strings I would recommend using a POST with an appropriate request body, or passing the entire list as an appropriately encoded JSON string. However, with simple strings you just need to append each value to the request URL appropriately and Jersey will deserialize it for you. So given the following example endpoint:

```
@Path("/service/echo") public class MyServiceImpl {
    public MyServiceImpl() {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/withlist")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response echoInputList(@QueryParam("list") final List<String> inputList) {
        return Response.ok(inputList).build();
    }
}
```

Your client would send a request corresponding to:

> GET http://example.com/services/echo?list=Hello&list=Stay&list=Goodbye

Which would result in `inputList` being deserialized to contain the values 'Hello', 'Stay' and 'Goodbye'

Comment: Thanks for your answer Perception! But I'd like to find out if it is possible to do a GET with a List as query parameter using Jersey client.

Comment: Can you please tell how to create such list at client side, as my clients are android and ios. Obvious we dont want to create key=value&key=value manuall

Comment: what if it sends `list[0]=Hello&list[1]=Stay` ? how to manage that?

Answer (score 5):

i agree with you about alternative solutions which you mentioned above

```
1. Use POST instead of GET;
2. Transform the List into a JSON string and pass it to the service.
```

and its true that you can't add `List` to `MultiValuedMap` because of its impl class `MultivaluedMapImpl` have capability to accept String Key and String Value. which is shown in following figure

[image]

still you want to do that things than try following code.

**Controller Class**

```
package net.yogesh.test;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Path("test")
public class TestController {
       @Path("testMethod")
       @GET
       @Produces("application/text")
       public String save(
               @QueryParam("list") List<String> list) {

           return  new Gson().toJson(list) ;
       }
}
```

**Client Class**

```
package net.yogesh.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String op = doGet("http://localhost:8080/JerseyTest/rest/test/testMethod");
        System.out.println(op);
    }

    private static String doGet(String url){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"string1,string2,string3"});

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        String lst = (list.toString()).substring(1, list.toString().length()-1);
        params.add("list", lst);

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(config);
        WebResource resource = client.resource(url);

        ClientResponse response = resource.queryParams(params).type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").get(ClientResponse.class);
        String en = response.getEntity(String.class);
        return en;
    }
}
```

hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 5):

One could use the queryParam method, passing it parameter name and an array of values:

```
    public WebTarget queryParam(String name, Object... values);
```

Example (jersey-client 2.23.2):

```
    WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(URI.create("http://localhost"));
    target.path("path")
            .queryParam("param_name", Arrays.asList("paramVal1", "paramVal2").toArray())
            .request().get();
```

This will issue request to following URL:

```
    http://localhost/path?param_name=paramVal1&param_name=paramVal2
```

Answer (score 3):

GET Request with JSON Query Param

```
package com.rest.jersey.jerseyclient;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientGET {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {               

            String BASE_URI="http://vaquarkhan.net:8080/khanWeb";               
            Client client = Client.create();    
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI);

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

            /*if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
            }
*/
            String output = webResource.path("/msg/sms").queryParam("search","{\"name\":\"vaquar\",\"surname\":\"khan\",\"ext\":\"2020\",\"age\":\"34\""}").get(String.class);
            //String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);                         

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Post Request :

```
package com.rest.jersey.jerseyclient;

import com.rest.jersey.dto.KhanDTOInput;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

public class JerseyClientPOST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            KhanDTOInput khanDTOInput = new KhanDTOInput("vaquar", "khan", "20", "E", null, "2222", "8308511500");                      

            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

            clientConfig.getFeatures().put( JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

               // final HTTPBasicAuthFilter authFilter = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password);
               // client.addFilter(authFilter);
               // client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

            //
            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://vaquarkhan.net:12221/khanWeb/messages/sms/api/v1/userapi");

              ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class, khanDTOInput);


            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code :" + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Server response .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: seeing example of Client resource was what I needed :) thanks