# Restful API Get manipulated data from resource

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

I am new to rest, I have an entity called availableJobPositions. I want to get most Interesting job by sending a person skills. which url is good in restful:

```
api/positions/skill/most-intersting?skills[]=php&skills[]=mysql
```

or

```
api/most-intersting-job?skills[]=php&skills[]=mysql
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing array in GET for a REST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944410/passing-array-in-get-for-a-rest-call)

Comment: @haldo while it might be a duplicate, the truth is, that in a REST architecture the characters used inside a URI is not of relevance as the URIs are just invoked and clients should not attempt to parse are deduce some knowledge from it. The whole URI itself (including path, matrix and query parameters) is just a pointer to a resource, nothing more, nothing less. Link relation names and text describing that URI are there for, similar to the Web i.e. As such this question does not really have a right or wrong answer.